# SSL Handshake error with Mapr Streams to Azure

Tags: azure, ssl, apache-kafka, mapr-streams

The error described below occurs in MapR 6.0, but I fail to see any MapR-specificity, so guess it could happen in other enrironments..

I'm mirroring a MapR Stream to Azure Kafka-enabled Event Hub, combining these two documents:

[Mirroring Topics from a MapR Cluster to an Apache Kafka Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-kafka-mirror-maker-tutorial)

[Use Apache Kafka MirrorMaker with Azure Event Hubs for Kafka Ecosystem | Microsoft Docs](https://mapr.com/docs/52/MapR_Streams/mirroring_ms_to_ak.html)

There seems to be some activity happening in Azure when I run the mirror making command, but in the end it fails with this exception list:

```
FATAL [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread failure due to (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$FutureFailure.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:1344)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:969)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:897)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:774)
at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerProducer.send(MirrorMaker.scala:709)
at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread$$anonfun$run$6.apply(MirrorMaker.scala:431)
at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread$$anonfun$run$6.apply(MirrorMaker.scala:431)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread.run(MirrorMaker.scala:431)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1529)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1214)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1186)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeWrap(SslTransportLayer.java:435)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:301)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:255)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:79)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:460)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:398)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:330)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:992)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:989)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1467)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:389)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:469)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:328)
... 8 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1601)
... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
... 23 more
[2018-08-20 04:30:07,862] FATAL [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread exited abnormally, stopping the whole mirror maker. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
```

I tried exporting the SSL certificate of my eventhub and importing it to cacerts ([as shown here](http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html)), but to no avail. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to follow the directions from the following link, then use the generated cert-file in the configuration for the producer.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html